# Отмена изменений объекта MVVM WPF EF6

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, automapper

У меня есть проект для моего колледжа. В нем я пытаюсь реализовать MVVM + WPF + EF6. По ходу возникла проблема, которую я не могу решить уже **слишком** долго.

Немного о том что я уже смог сделать:

Есть класс *MedRecordViewModel* - view model с свойством *selecteditem* и определёнными CRUD командами, есть view *MedRecord**Edit*** в которую передаётся в качестве datacontexts'a - MedRecordViewModel.

[image: MedRecordEdit]

Суть проблемы:
Я не могу сделать отмену изменений, которые сразу же применяются из-за реализованного inotifypropertychanged интерфейса.

Я нашел решение по типу "создать клон объекта с помощью AutoMapper'a и в случае отмены просто перезаписать в текущий selecteditem созданный клон", но из-за того что автомапер создает полностью новый объект, этот объект судя по всему перестает отслеживаться моей ObservableCollection.

Вопросы:

1. Как правильно делать отмену изменений ?
2. Как померить automapper с EF?

Comment: в где в вашем `MVVM` находится `Model`?

Comment: Я бы сделал в  MedRecordViewModel  свойство Вашего студента и по команде, обрабатывающей выбор студента (или в конструкторе, если у вас отдельная вьюха под него) ,  писал бы  selecteditem  в это свойство. А в случае отмены (в обработчике CancelCommand),  возвращал бы его назад. И я правильно понимаю Вас, что запись в БД идет  непосредственно в момент изменения любого свойства? Если так, это не очень хорошая идея (мягко говоря). Я бы повесил запись в БД на команду, обрабатывающую нажатие на кнопку "Готово",

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: работа примера]

Можно воспользоваться реализацией `IEditableObject` в классе модели

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged, IEditableObject
{
    //ссылка на экземпляр хранения предыд.значений на время редактирования
    private Person _tempValues;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public int Id { get; set; }

    private int _OrderNumber;
    public int OrderNumber
    {
        get => _OrderNumber;
        set
        {
            _OrderNumber = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(OrderNumber)));
        }
    }


    private string _FirstName;
    public string FirstName
    {
        get => _FirstName;
        set
        {
            _FirstName = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(FirstName)));
        }
    }

    private string _LastName;
    public string LastName
    {
        get => _LastName;
        set
        {
            _LastName = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(LastName)));
        }
    }

    #region Реализация IEditableObject

    /// <summary>
    /// Когда начинается редактирование
    /// </summary>
    public void BeginEdit()
    {
        _tempValues = new Person
        {
            Id = this.Id,
            OrderNumber = this.OrderNumber,
            FirstName = this.FirstName,
            LastName = this.LastName
        };
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Когда редактирование завершено
    /// </summary>
    public void EndEdit()
    {
        _tempValues = null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Когда редактирование отменяется
    /// </summary>
    public void CancelEdit()
    {
        if (_tempValues == null) return;

        this.Id = _tempValues.Id;
        this.OrderNumber = _tempValues.OrderNumber;
        this.FirstName = _tempValues.FirstName;
        this.LastName = _tempValues.LastName;
    } 
    #endregion
}
```

Например `DataGrid` что называется "из коробки" поддерживает вызов соотв.методов, и в частности вызывает `CancelEdit()` если во время редактирования ячейки нажать Esc. 
Ну, а в случае редактирования в текстбоксах можно поступить так

```
public class MainViewModel : IMainViewModel, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly IPersonRepository _repo;
    private Person _selectedPerson;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    //ctor
    public MainViewModel(IPersonRepository repository)
    {
            _repo = repository ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(repository));
    }

    public async Task LoadData()
    {
        People = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

        var result = await _repo.GetPeopleOrderedByLastName();
        List<Person> people = result.ToList();
        for (int i = 0; i < people.Count; i++)
        {
            people[i].OrderNumber = i + 1;
            People.Add(people[i]);
        }

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Коллекция для ListView
    /// </summary>
    public ObservableCollection<Person> People { get; private set; }


    /// <summary>
    /// Выделенный в ListView человек
    /// </summary>
    public Person SelectedPerson
    {
        get => _selectedPerson;
        set
        {
            //отменяем редактирование предыдущ.
            _selectedPerson?.CancelEdit();

            _selectedPerson = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SelectedPerson)));

            //начинаем редактирование
            _selectedPerson?.BeginEdit();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Кнопка Готово
    /// </summary>
    private ICommand _AddCommand;
    public ICommand AddCommand
    {
        get => _AddCommand = _AddCommand ?? new RelayCommand(OnAdd);
    }
    private async void OnAdd()
    {
        if (SelectedPerson == null) return;

        //заканчиваем редактирование
        SelectedPerson.EndEdit();
        //обновляем в БД
        await _repo.UpdatePerson(SelectedPerson);
        SelectedPerson = null;
        //перезагружаем список из БД
        await LoadData();
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Кнопка Отмена
    /// </summary>
    private ICommand _CancelCommand;
    public ICommand CancelCommand
    {
        get => _CancelCommand = _CancelCommand ?? new RelayCommand(OnCancel);
    }
    private void OnCancel()
    {
        if (SelectedPerson == null) return;

        //отменяем редактирование
        SelectedPerson.CancelEdit();
    }
}
```

Весь пример можно посмотреть [здесь](https://github.com/bulsond/SOrusExamples/tree/master/ExEditableObject).

Comment: Хм, а почему `IMainViewModel`, а не простая какая то реализация в классе? Вот есть у меня грешок, до сих пор не пойму для чего нужны интерфейсы, может вы сможете это объяснить?)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ это просто моя привычка начинать написание с абстракций, да и, как её там называют, слабую связанность никто не отменял...